# Cannot require customer group during registration in EE

Tags: magento-enterprise, customer-group, customer-attribute, enterprise-1.14

I'd like to require customers to select a group when creating an account. It seems that I should be able to from within the Manage Customer Attributes section but the form options I need to modify are disabled.

Comment: I'm assuming the form field is disabled because users shouldn't be the ones choosing which customer group they're in.

Answer (score 2):

You can use your browser's inspection tool to remove the `disabled` attribute for that form field. This will set the necessary values in the DB, but it will not make the field available to users in the frontend. You will have to update an attribute parameter - and an important one at that. You therefore should do this via update script, one which executes in scope of `Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Setup` (though this is best practice/academic - `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup` would work for this case).

```
/* @var $installer Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Setup */
$installer = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/setup','customer_setup');

$installer->startSetup();

//make visible to EAV form block
$installer->updateAttribute(
    'customer',
    'group_id',
    'is_user_defined',
    1
);

//set to proper forms
$groupAttr = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'group_id');

$groupAttr->setData(
    array(
        'adminhtml_checkout',        # REQUIRED
        'adminhtml_customer,         # REQUIRED
        'customer_account_create',   # YOUR REQUIREMENT
        //'checkout_register',       # optional
        //'customer_account_edit'    # optional
    )
));

$groupAttr->save();

$installer->endSetup();
```

The EE EAV form block (`Enterprise_Eav_Block_Form`) loads customer attributes based on `eav_attributes.is_user_defined` = 1.  `is_user_defined` denotes that the attribute is not native and - in the case of some entities - allowed to be removed.

**THERE IS ONE MASSIVE CAVEAT:** Normally, customers are not allowed to manage their own grouping, and there are business features (some EE-specific) which rely on this. Because of this (?) there are no checks that the `group_id` value being provided is "sane". You may want to create a new backend model for the `group_id` attribute and use it for validation during save operations.

Comment: It seems that I didn't and don't fully grasp the group purpose as defined by Magento. It seems that the best action to take is to create a new customer attribute that defines the customer type and open up an investigation into if we are using Magento's groups as they are intended. Thank you for your detailed response.

Comment: Your use case isn't necessarily *against* the intention of customer groups, it's just that you are giving more visibility & control of this customer facet than is typical.